# Newbie Camera Struggle

Tags: camera

I cannot figure out how to position the camera to see a large map I've created and want to follow a path over it. I've messed with scaling the map, the camera, and can never get the map in the camera view to start. Either only part of the image shows and the rest of screen is black or the higher I take the camera all I get is a black screen. Attached screenshot image is the shot I'd like to get with the camera:

[image: Desired Camera View]

Can somebody explain what I need to do or let me know if I'm trying to do something that is not possible?

Comment: If this is the view you want, press `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`Numpad 0`, this sets the camera to this view. If you do not want to accidentally lose this view when navigating the viewport, make sure in the sidebar (press `N` if it is not visible) under the _View_ tab, _View Lock_ > _Lock_ > _Camera to View_ is not enabled. For things disappearing make sure the _Clip Start/End_ values in the _Camera Properties_ are set to reasonable distances that easily cover the object(s) you want to see in render.

Comment: For everything else it would be good to know how you've setup the scene. What kind of object is the map and how did you put it in the scene? How do you want to make the camera move over the map? And please use proper screenshots, do not take pictures of your monitor.

Comment: Welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue in such way that anyone searching for a similar problem may easily find it. Use the [edit] link above, remove anything superfluous, avoid words like "*this*","*issue with*" or "*question about*". Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, answers you get depend heavily on how inviting it is. See ["*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?*"](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Answer (score 0):

Solved thanks to Gordon Brinkman. Supplied answer about "Clip Start/End" values was the key to solve the problem: setting those values and changing camera from "perspective" to "orthographic" finally got the map in the camera view at the angle I was looking for.